# How do I create a graph with randomly directed edges starting from a undirected graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, data-structures

I have an undirected graph $G$.  How would I randomly assign directions to some fraction $p$ of the edges?  How might I do this efficiently / quickly provided I have a large graph structure?

For example, to assign a graph random edge weights, I might write:

```
GraphWithRandomWeights = Graph[EdgeList[G], EdgeWeight -> Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {abc, 1, Length[EdgeList[G]]}]];
```

Comment: A similar question was asked in the middle of [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23321/making-findshortestpath-a-little-bit-sloppy).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a built-in function `DirectedGraph[ (*your undirected graph*) , "Random"]` for this job:

```
myGraph = RandomGraph[{10, 13},
  VertexLabels -> Table[v -> Style[v, 20], {v, 10}],
  ImagePadding -> 20, VertexSize -> Medium]
```

[image: myGraph]

```
DirectedGraph[myGraph, "Random"]
```

[image: myDirectGraph]

(Note the layout may not be the same as `myGraph`.)

## Edit:

As OP asked in a comment, if you only want a fraction of the total edges to be directed, then the best way might be to manipulate the adjacency matrix:

```
myAdj = AdjacencyMatrix[myGraph]
```

[image: myAdj]

Suppose the edges we want to become directed are those between vertices $2\sim 4$, $1\sim 9$, $1\sim 10$, $5\sim 7$:

```
directEdgeSet = {{2, 4}, {1, 9}, {1, 10}, {5, 7}};
```

So a randomly constructed directed adjacency matrix would be:

```
myDirectAdj = ReplacePart[myAdj,
      Thread[RandomSample /@ directEdgeSet -> 0]
     ]
```

[image: myDirectAdj]

The corresponding graph is

```
AdjacencyGraph[myDirectAdj,
 DirectedEdges -> True,
 VertexLabels -> Table[v -> Style[v, 20], {v, 10}],
 ImagePadding -> 20, VertexSize -> Medium]
```

[image: my partial directed graph]

Comment: @Sylvia is it possible for me to only direct a fraction of the total edges?

Comment: @Peter Directed edges and undirected edges can not coexist in a same graph by [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph). Please compare the difference of `AdjacencyGraph[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}, DirectedEdges -> True]` and `AdjacencyGraph[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}]`.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: @Peter You're welcome.

Comment: How do i work with the function DirectedGraph[myGraph, "Random"] ?
Is there in networkx package?

Comment: @PeymanArebi Sorry I never used or heard of networkx package. Regarding DirectedGraph, please refer to the official documentation: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirectedGraph.html .